# Use ant path as property in bootclasspath

Tags: java, ant, bootclasspath

In the ant script, I have `path` set:

```
<path id="classpath.id">
  <pathelement path="somepath_1" />
  ...
  <pathelement path="somepath_n" />
</path>
```

So that I use it in `java` task:

```
<java ... classpathref="classpath.id">
 ...
</java>
```

How do I use the `classpath.id` to set `bootclasspath` in `java` ant task similar to:

```
<java ...>
  <jvmarg value="-Xbootclasspath/a:${myjar.jar}${path.separator}${classpath.id}"/>
</java>
```

`${classpath.id}` is not known to the ant at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a special syntax for getting the value of something referred to by an Ant reference id.  Use `${ant.refid:classpath.id}` instead of `${classpath.id}`.

See [*Getting the value of a Reference with ${ant.refid:}*](https://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#ant.refid) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, these are possible solutions:

**Using ${ant.refid:} prefix**

It's the cleanest solution and all the credit goes to [martin clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183172/martin-clayton) for [pointing to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38392118/1026104). Just use

```
<java ...>
  <jvmarg value="Xbootclasspath/a:${myjar.jar}${path.separator}${ant.refid:classpath.id}"/>
</java>
```

**Creating a new property**

```
<property name="classpath.property" refid="classpath.id"/>
<java ...>
  <jvmarg value="Xbootclasspath/a:${myjar.jar}${path.separator}${classpath.property}"/>
</java>
```

**Using bootclasspath and bootclasspathref**

While `bootclasspathref` is available only to [`javac`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html), `bootclasspath` can be nested in [`java`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html):

```
<java fork="true" ...>
  <bootclasspath>
    <path refid="classpath.id"/>
    <pathelement path="${myjar.jar}" />
  </bootclasspath>
</java>
```

There are complications with this solution, though.

- `<bootclasspath>` replaces the actual bootclasspath, removing java's jars from it, and there is no `<bootclasspath/a>` nested tag in ant so far.
- In java SE 9, the *-Xboothclasspath* property is no longer available. There only is *-Xboothclasspath/a*, so `<bootclasspath>` does not work there.